# starting new Activities from ImageButtons

Tags: android, android-activity, imagebutton

I have MainMenu. There's 3 different ImageButtons for starting new Activities. Everything work fine, but I wondering is possible another way to code this. I took this from example code with one button, and I think its not look good: setting **new OnClickListener()** for each button.

```
public class MainMenu extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

ImageButton firstModule;
ImageButton secondModule;
ImageButton thirdModule;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_menu);

    //init buttons
    firstModule =  (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    secondModule = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
    thirdModule =  (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);

    firstModule.setOnClickListener(this);
    secondModule.setOnClickListener(this);
    thirdModule.setOnClickListener(this);
}
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.imageButton1:
        startActivity(new Intent(MainMenu.this, BasicFunctions.class));
        break;
    case R.id.imageButton2:
        startActivity(new Intent(MainMenu.this, GpsModule.class));
        break;
    case R.id.imageButton3:
        startActivity(new Intent(MainMenu.this, Graphic3D.class));
        break;
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The more elegant way is to implement `View.OnClickListener` inside your `Activity` and then process clicks inside the `onClick()` method of your `Activity`. It gives you a `View` object as an argument, you can retrieve the view's id using the `view.getId()` method, then you can use the `switch` block to implement actions for every `Button` in your layout. Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried Your solution (first post edited) but buttons are not react on clicking. I have no Idea for now.

Comment: I made a breakpoint in switch() and it's seems the method OnClic() is never used.

Comment: I forgot to set onClickListener for each button, post edited. Thanks a lot for help Egor!

Comment: @MariuszChw, You're welcome! Sorry, I wasn't able to answer on your comments, but I'm glad you've got it going.

Comment: I think that the way You explain me what to do with it, it's the best method for newbie programmers. You didn't paste me final code. I got explanation what should I do, it forced me to start thinking, to understand mechanism of this operation. Thanks a lot again

Comment: @MariuszChw, Very glad to hear that! Yeah, I really think that to understand something you should start thinking and try to figure it out by yourself rather than just getting a working solution. Good luck!